# how to include a set of integers in the validation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working with spring boot, one of the inputs of my object, has  to accept only a set of integers, and I'm not getting it.

This is my last approach:

```
    @Pattern(regexp="\\d{1111}|\\d{2222}|\\d{3333}|\\d{4444}", message="The value has to be '1111','2222','3333' or '4444'")
private int code;
```

This is not valid because I'm getting this error:

```
 "statusText": "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Pattern' validating type 'java.lang.Integer'. Check configuration for 'code'",
```

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `@Pattern` [only works on strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html).

You could use a [`@Digits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Digits.html) validator to validate how many digits you must have in the integer part: https://www.baeldung.com/javax-bigdecimal-validation#3-digits

If this doesn't work for you, then you will have to write your own custom validator: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator#custom-validation

Answer (score 1):

`@Pattern` Annotation works **only** with strings and not integers. You could migrate your `int` to a `String` if that is suitable. Then it would work.

You could also implement your own `Validator` as seen [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator).

Answer (score 0):

As others have already answered @Pattern does not work with integers, but with strings(CharSequence to be more precise). But i want to note that your regex pattern does not match the error message.

The pattern you specified means - match a number with a length of 1111 digits, or length of 2222 digits, and so on.

According to the message you need pattern like `^1111$|^2222$|^3333$|^4444$` or `^([1234])\1{3}$`, which means match 1111, or 2222, or 3333, or 4444 exactly.

Answer (score -1):

One the solution can be

```
@Pattern(regex = "[0-9]+")
private Integer code;
```

Comment: `@Pattern` is not applicable to `int`

Comment: @Stefan Zhelyazkov I think that I correct it.

Comment: The documentation says that `@Pattern` is only applicable to instances of `CharSequence` (String, StringBuilder, etc): https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html